# Linux wc command in C

Tags: c, strings, reinventing-the-wheel, io

I'm working on my implementaion of the linux wc command. I finally have something that is working properly (with no options yet) but i think it needs a lot of "cleaning". I mean, i highly disrespect the "do not repeat yourself rule" and i want to hear some ideas on how can i polish this up a bit.

Here 's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

typedef struct Total{ //stores the Total count of lines words and bytes
  int lines;
  int words;
  int bytes;
} Total;

Total* new_Total(int lines, int words, int bytes){ //constructor function for Total
  Total* t = (Total*)malloc(sizeof(Total));
  t->lines = lines;
  t->words = words;
  t->bytes = bytes;
  return t;
}

void updateTotal(Total *t, int lines, int words, int bytes){ //updates Total counters
  t->lines += lines;
  t->words += words;
  t->bytes += bytes;
}

void readStdin(Total* t, char c){ //reads from stdin, counts and prints
  int lines = 0, words = 0, bytes = 0, startWord = 0;
  char ch;
  while((ch=fgetc(stdin)) != EOF){//count the bytes, lines and words
    bytes++;
    if (ch == '\n'){
      lines++;
    }
    if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n' && ch != '\r' && ch != '\t'){ //if there's a visible char, there's a word
      startWord = 1;
    }
    if ((ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\r' || ch == '\t') && startWord == 1){ //when the word ends
      words++; //increment the word coutner
      startWord = 0; //reset word finder
    }
  }
  updateTotal(t, lines, words, bytes);
  if (c == '\0'){ //if the command was called with no arguments
    printf ("%d %d %d\n", lines, words, bytes);
  }
  else{
    printf ("%d %d %d %c\n", lines, words, bytes, c);
  }
}

void readFile(Total *t, char* filename, FILE* fp){
  int lines = 0, words = 0, bytes = 0, startWord = 0;
  char ch;
  if (fp == NULL){
    printf("%s: No such file or drectory\n", filename);
    exit(1);
  }
  while ((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF){ //count the bytes, lines and words
    bytes++;
    if (ch == '\n'){
      lines++;
    }
    if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n' && ch != '\r' && ch != '\t'){
      startWord = 1;
    }
    if ((ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\r' || ch == '\t') && startWord == 1){
      words++;
      startWord = 0;
    }
  }
  updateTotal(t, lines, words, bytes);
  printf("%d %d %d %s\n", lines, words, bytes, filename);
}

void readArgs(Total* t, int argc, char* argv[]){
  FILE* fp;
  for (int i=1; i<argc; i++){
    if (*argv[i] == '-'){//if a '-' is found, read from stdin
      readStdin(t, '-');
      clearerr(stdin);
    }
    else { //tries to read the file in argv[i]
      fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
      readFile(t, argv[i], fp);
      fclose(fp);
    }
  }
  if (argc > 2){ //if there's more than one file, print the total in the end
    printf("%d %d %d total\n", t->lines, t->words, t->bytes);
  }
  else {
    exit(0);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  Total* t = new_Total(0,0,0);
  if (argc<2){ //no arguments
    readStdin(t,'\0'); //pass /0 to readstin because as it is the only time it is called, there's no need to append the name of the argument
    return 0;
  }
  readArgs(t, argc, argv);
  free(t);
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, both in readStdin() and in readFile() i have the same piece of code that handles the counting. I've tried to make a function out of this using pointers but i gave up. Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Also, if you have any hint that has nothing to do with the problem that i mentioned, shoot it up!

Comment: Why describe it as *Linux* `wc` command?  `wc` has been around much longer than Linux has!

Answer (score 4):

A standard way to do this is to break the function up into smaller 'private' (`static`) functions, each with one thing to do. One can pass the default to the counting function in case we are not provided the argument. This allows separation of the code which counts and the UI.

`Total` is always going to be called with `(0, 0, 0)`, it's unnecessary to provide these arguments. In fact, the storage of `Total` in dynamic memory is probably unnecessary. No need to `updateTotal`, use of the counters directly is fine. In fact, there is going to be 1 `total`, might as well make it [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251083/the-initialization-of-static-variables-in-c).

`fgetc` returns an `int`, `char ch` is not enough to tell `EOF`, which is -1. You've defined `BUF_SIZE`, an excellent optimization, but never use it. I'd go from `fgetc` to `fgets`. Note that this assumes that the file is text and doesn't contain a `'\0'` inside, (eg, modified UTF-8.)

You've included `getopt` and `unistd`, making your code `POSIX C99`, but you're not using those. Removing them makes your code more general `C99` (now your code will compile on more compilers.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

//stores the Total count of lines words and bytes
struct Total {
    size_t lines, words, bytes;
} total;

//count the bytes, lines and words
//gives incorrect results on binary files with embedded 0
//a word is delimited by everything that {isgraph}
//using the unix definition of a text file, {lines = count('\n')}
static int readFile(FILE *fp) {
    char buffer[1024], b;
    int startWord = 1;
    size_t i;
    while(fgets(buffer, (int)sizeof buffer, fp)) {
        i = 0;
        do {
            b = buffer[i++];
            if(b == '\n') {
                /* This will not recognize '\l' in old Mac text files opened
                 with "wb"? Hmm. */
                total.lines++;
                startWord = 1;
            } else if(b == '\0') {
                break;
            } else if(isgraph(b)) {
                //if there's a visible char, there's a word
                if(startWord) total.words++, startWord = 0;
            } else {
                startWord = 1;
            }
        } while(1);
        total.bytes += i;
    }
    return ferror(fp) ? 0 : 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = 0;
    char *fn = "<no file>";
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        fn = argv[i];
        fp = fopen(fn, "r");
        if(!fp || !readFile(fp)) break;
        fclose(fp), fp = 0;
    }
    if(argc <= 1) readFile(stdin);
    if(fp) fclose(fp);
    if(errno) return perror(fn), EXIT_FAILURE;
    /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524675/2472827 */
    printf("%zu lines; %zu words; %zu bytes total.\n",
        total.lines, total.words, total.bytes);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Some see `typedef struct` as problematic, and, in my opinion, it's not needed here; see [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs). `INT_MAX` could be as little as [32,767](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/limits.h); it's never going to be less than zero, so I'd prefer `unsigned`, or `size_t` in this context. What if there are other chars besides `'\n', ' ', '\r', '\t'`? I've included `<ctype.h>` to get rid of the ambiguity. There was a bug counting the word at the end of the line. Now, a line is defined as the number of `'\n'` (UNIX style.) A word is delimited by `isgraph`.

Answer (score 3):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your program.

### Use only the required `#include`s

As far as I can tell, nothing from `<getopt.h>` is actually used, so that could be omitted.

### Eliminate unused definitions

The `BUF_SIZE` definition is not used and should be eliminated.

### Avoid allocating memory if possible

There's not really much need here for `malloc` and `free`.  The `Total` structure is small and easily fits on the stack frame.  Avoiding `malloc` means you'll never have to worry about `free`ing the memory later.

### Prefer a `switch` to a long `if...else`

The `while` loop only examines `ch` but it does so inefficiently because potentially, it examines the same character multiple times.  A `switch` would be more efficient, shorter and more easily understood here.

### Use `bool` where appropriate

The `startWord` variable is apparently being used as a boolean variable.  For that reason, I'd suggest using `#include <stdbool.h>` and declaring it as `bool`.

### Use `const` where practical

The `filename` argument is not and should not be altered by the `readFile` function.  For that reason, it would be better to declare that argument `const`.

### Consolidate code by combining cases

Instead of having completely separate `readStdin` and `readFile` functions, it would be sensible to simply retain only `readFile` and initialize the `FILE` structure like this:

```
FILE *file = (filename && filename[0] == '-') ? stdin : fopen(filename, "r");
```

### Use the appropriate `printf` format string

The code uses `%d` for the format string, but would it ever make sense for the passed arguments to be negative?  I would say not, and would suggest instead that these variables would more appropriately be `size_t` and that the format string should be `%lu` or `%u` depending on your compiler's implementation.

### Simplify code by using functions

There are four places in the code that use `printf` to show totals.  These could instead be reduced to a single place by creating a simple function:

```
static void report(const char *filename, size_t lines, size_t words, size_t letters) {
    printf("%5lu %5lu %5lu %s\n", lines, words, letters, filename);
}
```

### Don't quit after a single error

The way that `wc` works is that it will keep going to process other files if one happens not to exist.  To mimic that behavior, you'd have to alter your code to not `exit` if the file does not exist.

### Carefully consider whether a `struct` is worthwhile

I'm all for consolidating variables into meaningfully named `struct`s as you have done, but I think the code is simpler using the three plain variables.  Here's my complete version which incorporates all of these suggestions so that you can compare for yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static void count(const char *filename, size_t *lines, size_t *words, size_t *letters) {
    FILE *file = (filename && filename[0] == '-') ? stdin : fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("%s: No such file or drectory\n", filename);
        return;
    }
    bool inword = false;
    for (int ch = fgetc(file); ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(file)) {
        switch (ch) {
            case '\n':
                ++*lines;
                // fall through
            case ' ': 
            case '\r':
            case '\t':
                if (inword) {
                    ++*words;
                }
                inword = false;
                break;
            default:
                inword = true;                  
        }
        ++*letters;
    }
    fclose(file);
}

static void report(const char *filename, size_t lines, size_t words, size_t letters) {
    printf("%5lu %5lu %5lu %s\n", lines, words, letters, filename);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    size_t totallines = 0;
    size_t totalwords = 0;
    size_t totalletters = 0;
    if (argc < 2) {
        puts("Usage: wc filename [filename ...]");
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i=1; i < argc; ++i) {
        size_t lines = 0;
        size_t words = 0;
        size_t letters = 0;
        count(argv[i], &lines, &words, &letters);
        report(argv[i], lines, words, letters);
        totallines += lines;
        totalwords += words;
        totalletters += letters;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        report("total", totallines, totalwords, totalletters);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good advice. I would say that a `struct` is probably worthwhile, since the data are strongly linked together.

Comment: @NeilEdelman: Yes, I could definitely argue it either way.  In C++ I would definitely use a `class` (primarily for the `operator+=` and `ostream<<` functions) but I don't see as much benefit in this particular C code.  Grouping can be handy, but it's also pretty easy to remember three or four well-named variables.

Comment: I don't know C++ as well as C, but isn't a `struct` and a `class` the same wrt `operator`?

Comment: @NeilEdelman: The difference is that one can overload operators for custom `struct` or `class` types in C++, but one cannot overload operators at all in C.

Answer (score 2):

Don't cast the result of `malloc()`; it's unnecessary clutter and it makes it harder to make changes.  For the same reason, it's better to use the pointed-to value rather than the type as argument to `sizeof`:

```
Total *t = malloc(sizeof *t);
```

We need to test the result of `malloc()` is not null before using it, else we run into Undefined Behaviour.

However, it's unnecessary to use dynamic allocation at all.  Instead of `new_Total()` we could provide `init_Total()` to initialise an existing (e.g. stack-allocated) value:

```
void init_Total(Total *t, int lines, int words, int bytes)
{
    assert(t);
    //constructor function for Total
    t->lines = lines;
    t->words = words;
    t->bytes = bytes;
}
```

Then, `main()` can begin like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Total t;
    init_Total(&t, 0, 0, 0);
```

---

We can use a single function for files and `stdin`:

```
static bool readStream(Total *t, FILE* fp)
{
    // common code here
}

bool readFile(Total *t, char* filename)
{
    FILE *const f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!f) {
        perror(filename);
        return false;
    }
    return readStream(t, f) & fclose(f);
}

bool readStdin(Total *t)
{
    return readStream(t, stdin);
}
```

You might even feel that naming `readStdin()` is overkill, and simply call `readStream(t, stdin);` directly from `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i actually did it on my own so, if anyone's interested, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

typedef struct Counter{ //stores the count of lines, words, bytes and the value of starword
  int lines;
  int words;
  int bytes;
  int wordFlag; //when counting words, if one is found, set to 1. when digested, reset.
} Counter;

Counter* new_Counter(int lines, int words, int bytes, int wordFlag){ //constructor function for Counter
  Counter* t = (Counter*)malloc(sizeof(Counter));
  t->lines = lines;
  t->words = words;
  t->bytes = bytes;
  t->wordFlag = wordFlag;
  return t;
}

void updateTotal(Counter *t, int lines, int words, int bytes){ //updates the total counter
  t->lines += lines;
  t->words += words;
  t->bytes += bytes;
}

void count(char ch, Counter* cnt){//counts the bytes, lines and words
  cnt->bytes++; //if a char is passed, count it
  if (ch == '\n'){ //count each line
    cnt->lines++;
  }
  if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n' && ch != '\r' && ch != '\t'){ //if there's a visible char, there's a word
    cnt->wordFlag = 1;
  }
  if ((ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\r' || ch == '\t') && cnt->wordFlag == 1){ //when the word ends
    cnt->words++; //increment the word counter
    cnt->wordFlag = 0; //reset the flag
  }
}

void readStdin(Counter* t, char c){ //reads from stdin and prints
  Counter* cnt = new_Counter(0,0,0,0);
  char ch;
  while((ch=fgetc(stdin)) != EOF){
    count(ch, cnt);
  }
  updateTotal(t, cnt->lines, cnt->words, cnt->bytes);

  if (c == '\0'){ //if the command was called with no arguments
    printf ("%d %d %d\n", cnt->lines, cnt->words, cnt->bytes);
  }
  else{
    printf ("%d %d %d %c\n", cnt->lines, cnt->words, cnt->bytes, c);
  }
  free(cnt);
}

void readFile(Counter *t, char* filename, FILE* fp){
  Counter* cnt = new_Counter(0,0,0,0);
  char ch;
  if (fp == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "./my_wc: %s: No such file or directory\n", filename);
    exit(1);
  }
  while ((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF){ //count the bytes, lines and words
    count(ch, cnt);
  }
  updateTotal(t, cnt->lines, cnt->words, cnt->bytes);
  printf("%d %d %d %s\n", cnt->lines, cnt->words, cnt->bytes, filename);
}

void readArgs(Counter* t, int argc, char* argv[]){
  FILE* fp;
  for (int i=1; i<argc; i++){
    if (*argv[i] == '-'){//if a '-' is found, read from stdin
      readStdin(t, '-');
      clearerr(stdin);
    }
    else { //tries to read the file in argv[i]
      fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
      readFile(t, argv[i], fp);
      fclose(fp);
    }
  }
  if (argc > 2){ //if there's more than one file, print the Counter in the end
    printf("%d %d %d total\n", t->lines, t->words, t->bytes);
  }
  else {
    exit(0);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  Counter* t = new_Counter(0,0,0,0); //pointer to the total counter
  if (argc<2){ //no arguments
    readStdin(t,'\0'); //pass /0 to readstin because as it is the only time it is called, there's no need to append the name of the argument
    return 0;
  }
  readArgs(t, argc, argv);
  free(t);
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, i renamed the struct to Counter and i used it to store, not only the total counter, but also every temporary counter, then i implemented the function count() that does with the temporary counter values what those if statements in readStdin and readFile do.
If you still have any suggestions, please do not hesitate.